# Create all pairwise combinations of ids per set for multiple sets

Tags: sql, postgresql, combinations

I have a table `in_pairs` with pairs of ids, which define sets of ids. This is my input. I need to create a query or a function to insert the contents into the output table `out_pairs`, where all combinations of ids per set are present.

It is best illustrated on the example below.

In this minimal reproducible example, table `in_pairs` has entries that define 2 sets of ids (A and B). Each set is defined by ids that are connected in at least one tuple. Thus, ids 1, 2, 3, 4 form one set, let us call it A. Ids 5, 6, 7 form another set, called B, etc. Note that the sets are of variable sizes. The sets are defined purely from the data in `in_pairs`, which is the real case come from user input from another application.

The output table `out_pairs` is hard-coded in this minimal example. This is what I am trying to avoid in the real case, and to replace hard-coding with a query.

In the real case, there are ~25,000 sets with 2-6 (variable number) ids per set, a total of ~100,000 ids. The ids in the real case are not sequential as they are in the minimal example. **The most desired solution for me would be for table `out_pairs` to be a view, otherwise a materialized view, otherwise a table which I will recreate programmatically.**

input table:

```
drop table if exists in_pairs;

create temp table in_pairs
    as
select
    *
from (
        values
    -- set A = 1, 2, 3, 4
        (2, 1)
        , (3, 1)
        , (4, 1)
        , (1, 2)
        , (3, 2)
        , (4, 2)
    -- set B = 5, 6, 7
        , (6, 5)
        , (7, 5)
        , (5, 6)
        , (7, 6)
        ) as t (id1, id2)
    ;
```

desired output:

```
drop table if exists out_pairs;

create temp table out_pairs
    as
select
    *
from (
        values
    -- ids: 1, 2, 3, 4 = set A
        (1, 1) , (2, 1) , (3, 1) , (4, 1)
        , (1, 2) , (2, 2), (3, 2) , (4, 2)
        , (1, 3) , (2, 3), (3, 3) , (4, 3)
        , (1, 4) , (2, 4), (3, 4) , (4, 4)
    -- set B = 5, 6, 7
        , (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5),
        , (5, 6), (6, 6), (7, 6),
        , (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7),
        ) as t (id1, id2)
    ;
```

Here is the illustration of how sets are defined from tuples in the minimal example. A "set" is defined as a group of ids, all of which are connected to each other through tuples in `in_pairs`. So 1, 2, 3, 4 are all connected by tuples, and form one set. And 5, 6, 7 are also connected by tuples, and form another set:

[image: Sets in the minimal example]

Comment: How is the set defined within the data itself? Is there a field for it? If we had that, this should be a lot easier

Comment: @ps2goat Yes it would, wouldn't' it! Alas, there is no `set_id` column, just `id1` and `id2`. The sets are defined based on the data in `id1` and `id2`, which in turn come from user input in another application. Thank you for the idea, I will consider if it is possible to add `set_id` somehow. But that would require changing the application that generates `in_pairs`, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If there is no set_id field, there **must** be a function to derive it from id1 and id2. (that's why I used division by four)

Comment: Aha! you want connected components, (and maybe enumerate these) I think you could make a recursive query to implement a union-find algorithm.

Comment: I suggest you change the question table into something more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry : typo. I intended: question **title** ...

Comment: @wildplasser I am open to suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        -- Make some data
        -- ----------------
create table pairs AS
WITH chunks AS (
        select 1 + gs/4 AS grp
        , 1+gs AS item
        FROM generate_series(0,15) gs
        )
SELECT
        one.item AS one
        , two.item AS two
FROM chunks one
JOIN chunks two ON one.grp = two.grp
        AND one.item < two.item
        ;

-- SELECT * FROM pairs;

        -- We use the lowest member number as the group_id
        -- Find the numbers that dont have a peer with a lower number
        -- ----------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TEMP TABLE top AS
        SELECT distinct one FROM pairs p
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM pairs nx
                WHERE nx.two = p.one
                AND nx.one < p.one
                )
        ;

-- SELECT * FROM top;

        -- Collect the clusters.
        -- using top as the seeder
        ------------------------------
WITH recursive grps AS (
        SELECT t.one AS grp, t.one AS member
        FROM top t
UNION ALL
        SELECT g.grp, p.two AS member
        FROM grps g
        JOIN pairs p ON p.one = g.member
        )
SELECT * FROM grps
ORDER BY grp, member
        ;
```

---

Update, using the original `VALUES()` data:

---

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE pairs AS SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (2, 1) , (3, 1) , (4, 1) , (1, 2) , (3, 2) , (4, 2)
         , (6, 5) , (7, 5) , (5, 6) , (7, 6) )
         AS t (one, two) ;

        -- Multiply population
INSERT INTO pairs(one,two)
SELECT gs+one,gs+two
FROM pairs p0
CROSS JOIN generate_series(10,30, 10) gs
        ;

-- SELECT * FROM pairs;

        -- [assuming an undirected graph]
        -- order the pairs such that (one < two)
        -- ---------------------------------------
CREATE TEMP TABLE opairs AS
SELECT one, two
FROM pairs p1
WHERE one < two
UNION
SELECT two, one -- Mirrored
FROM pairs p2
WHERE two < one
        -- except if the mirrored one exists
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM pairs nx
        WHERE nx.one = p2.two
        AND nx.two = p2.one
        );

        -- Force indexes both ways
        -- SHOULD be unique
        -- [duplicate edges in a graph are meaningless]
        -- -----------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE opairs ADD UNIQUE (one, two);
ALTER TABLE opairs ADD UNIQUE (two, one);
VACUUM ANALYZE opairs;

\echo opairs:
SELECT * FROM opairs ORDER by one,two;

        -- We use the lowest member number as the group_id
        -- Find the numbers that dont have a peer with a lower number
        -- ----------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TEMP TABLE top AS
        SELECT DISTINCT one
        FROM opairs p
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM opairs nx
                WHERE nx.two = p.one
                AND nx.one < p.one
                )
        ;
\echo the top:
SELECT * FROM top ORDER BY one;

        -- Collect the clusters.
        -- using top as the seeder
        ------------------------------
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH recursive grps AS (
        SELECT t.one AS grp, t.one AS member
        FROM top t
UNION ALL
        SELECT g.grp, p.two AS member
        FROM grps g
        JOIN opairs p ON p.one = g.member
        )
SELECT * FROM grps
ORDER BY grp, member
        ;
```

Comment: Yes. This is only a Proof Of Concept. You should add a primary key on the temp table, and on the base table, including an FK on the peer-pointer.

Comment: I just used the generate_series() to create some data. Should work (technically) with your actual data, too. There are some details, though: do you want A->B to exclude or imply B->A? That is a symmetry you may want to tackle... Also: it should be guaranteed that your graph is (at most) a DAG. No cycles, please!

Comment: IIUC, my real data (and even my MRE) has cycles. Let me think if I can filter them out quickly before using your method... Also, some, but not all, tuples, will have their reverse tuple present. That is, sometimes (A, B) will also have (B, A) present in the `in_pairs`, and sometimes not. The data is based on user-generated inputs, hence it is complex. I am now even considering changing the application that writes `in_pairs`, to add the `set_id`, even though it is more work than I planned originally...

Comment: Maybe tomorrow i'll rework using your data. one<two is a standard cycle-killer. There is also LEAST(), but that won't be sargeable, so better avoid it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method works, and I learned a lot from your answer. Just one small note: in order to remove the dups in the last `SELECT` statement, I had to use `... SELECT distinct(grp, member) FROM grps`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example, as long as we have some way to define what values belong to a specific set. It could be a CTE that narrows the scope or a field inside the data that we can use.

In summary, a `cross join` gives you the cartesian product among rows, which seems to be what you're looking for.

```sql
With seta as (
    select 1 as value, 'a' as setid union ALL
    select 2 as value, 'a' as setid union ALL
    select 3 as value, 'a' as setid union ALL
    select 4 as value, 'a' as setid
),
setb as (
    select 5 as value, 'b' as setid union ALL
    select 6 as value, 'b' as setid union ALL
    select 7 as value, 'b' as setid union ALL
    select 8 as value, 'b' as setid
)
select a1.value, a2.value, a1.setid from seta a1 cross join seta a2
union all
select b1.value, b2.value, b2.setid from setb b1 cross join setb b2
;
```

This gives a result similar to what you want, you just need to figure out how to separate the values.
[image]

Comment: Isn't it just hard-coding the sets? I am trying to avoid hard-coding. I need to take as input `in_pairs` and generate `out_pairs` using sql query without hardcoding which id belong to which set.

Comment: you can update the CTEs to whatever the underlying app is really doing. You can take the sets in as an array parameter to a postgres function, for example.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing the application that writes `in_pairs`? All I have it that table. I am looking for a SQL query or function to figure out the sets programmatically, from the `in_pairs` tuples alone. I updated the question with a picture.

Comment: That would be business logic for you to figure out. I can't really help unless you give us the rules. E.g., are the sets always the same length? Or can you pass in rules about `n` values in set 1, `m`  values in set 2, etc? Define that, and it will be much easier to assist you. If it's just data in a table with no way to order/group, then I'd say you'd be guessing most of the time.

Comment: No, the sets are variable length, and the length is unknown at the time the data is accessed in `in_pairs`. But the rule is clear: the set is a group if ids, where all ids are connected by at least one tuple. The rule is enough for the human to derive the sets and write `out_pairs` in the example shown, see also the picture. I am not sure how to encode this in SQL.

Comment: oh, I think I see what you mean, now. We have to find the set based on which pairs link to each other.